# Haskell ERROR - Unresolved overloading - Ambiguous type variable `a0' arising from a use of `print'

Tags: haskell, types, typeclass

This question is based on an example from the book "Haskell Programming from first principles".  In the chapter on Typeclasses, an example that's not right was shown.  I'm trying to make it work:

```
class Numberish a where
  fromNumber :: Integer -> a
  toNumber :: a -> Integer
newtype Age =
  Age Integer
  deriving (Eq, Show)
instance Numberish Age where
  fromNumber n = Age n
  toNumber (Age n) = n
```

The function toNumber works, but fromNumber doesn't work.  The error when I use HUGS is "ERROR - Unresolved overloading".  When I use GHCi, the error begins with "Ambiguous type variable 'a0' arising from a use of 'print' prevents the constraint '(Show a0)' from being solved".

I've tried to change the newtype and directly redeclare the instances (and using `deriving Eq` only instead of both Eq and Show), but the same error recurred:

```
newtype Age a =
  Age Integer
  deriving Eq
instance Show (Age a) where
  show (Age a) = "Age " ++ show a 
instance Show a => Numberish (Age a) where
  fromNumber n = Age n
  toNumber (Age n) = n
```

Is there a way to make fromNumber work?  For example, if we input `fromNumber 1`, the output should be `Age 1`.

Following the latest answers, I've tried the new inputs in GHCi based on the code I changed and screen captured the findings.  `fromNumber 42 :: Age String` works.

[image]

I've also tried `fromNumber 42 :: Age` in GHCi based on the original example code, and it works too.

[image]

Comment: You can not use `Age a`, since `Age n`, means it is a `Age Integer` object. By using `Age a`, it means any type `a` can be used, as long as it is an instance of `Show`.

Comment: I would also advise to use GHC, since Hugs is not actively maintained anymore. The last rlease was more than 13 years ago.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem: Sorry, I made a mistake. The original example only has `newtype Age =`.  I was experimenting with `newtype Age a =` but it failed too.  I've corrected my original post.

Comment: `fromNumber` works, but it is unclear what `a` should be. If you use `fromNumber 42 :: Age String`, for example, it will normally print the `Age 42` object.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem: I assume you are working with the original example, not the one I changed.  When I tried `fromNumber 42 :: Age String`, I get an error too:  
Expected kind '* -> *', but `Age' has kind '*' 
In an expression type signature: Age String 
In the expression: fromNumber 42 :: Age String 
In an equation for 'it': it = fromNumber 42 :: Age String

Comment: The `fromNumber 42 :: Age String` should work with the second version. The "kind" error message sounds like it came from the first version.

Comment: This is getting confused. Your screenshot says "test06.hs". What exactly is the code in that file? It would help a lot if you were precise about exactly which code gave which error message. Your posts so far strongly suggest confusion about this.

Comment: @maxloo: then you are still working with the `newtype Age = ...`, since then there is no type parameter. In the second example (with `newtype Age a = ...`), giving a hint `:: Age String` should work.

Comment: @PaulJohnson: "test06.hs" is just a haskell script file I use to keep my scripts for testing.  I've commented out all the irrelevant scripts.

Comment: Yes, but what *exactly* was in that file at the time you got the error message? The "no instance" message suggests that the derived "Show" instance you had in your first example isn't there any more. Please edit your post to show the exact code you are running and the exact error message you got.

Comment: @PaulJohnson: Thanks, I got it to work using your suggestions.  I've updated my post to reflect both the original code and the code I tried.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem: Thanks for the hints.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first sample, the problem is with the type in the expression

```
fromNumber 5
```

GHCi only knows that the result type is some instance of `Numberish`, but it can't tell which one. The fact that it has only one to choose from isn't important.

You can tell GHCi which type to use, and then it will be happy:

```
fromNumber 5 :: Age
```

If you were using this in an actual program the odds are that something else would tell the compiler which type it was; you would be doing other age-specific things with the value, like storing it in a record or passing it as a parameter to a function. The problem arises in cases like this where the value isn't being used for anything, so the compiler can't narrow it down.

The code in the second part is less clear; you have given `Age` a type parameter which is not used. This is known as a [*phantom type*](https://wiki.haskell.org/Phantom_type), and I'm not sure if you meant to do that. These are used when you want to tag a value with a type for some other reason than knowing the contents. So with the second version `fromNumber 42 :: Age String` should work because `String` has a `Show` instance, as required for your `Numberish` instance.